# How to change <li> position after animation using jquery?

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, slider, wordpress-theming

I have a jquery image slider that is set to move the images -100% to the left.
When the image gets to left:-100%; is there a way to have it move back to the beginning of the cycle?

```
<div id="homeslider" class="firefly_slider_wrapper">
    <div class="firefly_slider">
        <ul id="ffslider">
            <li class="slide">
                <div class="slideplacment">
                    <img src="" name="0" />
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="slide">
                <div class="slideplacment">
                    <img src="" name="1" /> 
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

*The script looks like this:*

```
jQuery(window).load(function(){ 
var tl2 = new TimelineMax({onComplete: upDatePosition});
var imgArray = [];
var imgLength = 0;
var photoContWidth = 0;
var imgWidth = 0;
n = jQuery("#ffslider li").length;

function setDefaults(){ 
      imgLength = jQuery('#ffslider li').length;
      photoContWidth = (imgLength * 100) + '%';
      for(var i=0; i<imgLength; i++){
                jQuery('#ffslider li').eq(i).attr('name',i);            
                jQuery('#ffslider li').eq(i).css('left', (i * 100) + "%");
                imgArray.push(jQuery('#ffslider li').eq(i));
      } 
        startAnimation();
    };

    function startAnimation(){
        tl2.to(imgArray, 1, {left:'-=100' + '%', delay:3});
    }

    function upDatePosition(){
        for(var i=0; i<imgLength; i++){
            if((imgArray[i].css('left') <= -100 + '%')){
              imgArray[i].css("left",  (n - 1) * '100' + '%'); 
            } 
        }
      startAnimation();
    }
    setDefaults();
});
```

Its dynamic and used in a WordPress theme.

Comment: Please provide the code you have so far. This isn't sufficient enough.

Comment: Considering that an `<UL>` holds a set of `<LI>`s you can remove the first and append to the end. But it'll be better if we see your code.

Comment: @JonathasPacífico that is exactly what I want to do but just cant figure out how to make it work

Comment: @user1887669, does the previous answers helped you? If it doesn't just let me know and we'll find a way.

Answer (score 0):

The [`.animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) function has a callback method that you can use.
Here's a quick example

### HTML

```
<div></div>
```

### CSS

```
div
{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
}
```

### JQuery

```
$("div").click(function() {
    $(this).animate({left: '-100%'}, 1000, function() {
        alert('Move left animation finished...');
        $(this).css({left: 0});
    });
});
```

### JSFiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/7BVz4/1/

Answer (score 0):

To extend my previous answer; here's a practical example:

### HTML

```
<div class="rotator-container">
    <div class="rotator">
        <span id="s1"></span>
        <span id="s2"></span>
        <span id="s3"></span>
    </div>
</div>

<a href="#">Show/hide</a>
```

### CSS

```
.rotator-container
{
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.rotator
{
    width: 3000px;
}

span
{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    display: block;
    float: left;
}

#s1 { background-color: red; }
#s2 { background-color: green; }
#s3 { background-color: blue; }

.sized
{
    width: 250px;
    height: 110px;
}
```

### JQuery

```
// Initialise...
d();

function d() {
    // Remember our parent and first child elements
    parent = $('.rotator');
    firstChild = parent.find('span:first');

    // Slide left animation
    firstChild.animate({'margin-left': -100}, 1000, function() {
        // Remove the current element and reset the margin
        firstChild.remove().css({'margin-left': 0});
        // Add the element back to the end of the parent
        parent.append(firstChild);

        // Callback to self (repeat the animation!)
        d();
    });  
};

$('a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.rotator-container').toggleClass('sized');
});
```

### JSFiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/gvee/tuuVe/